# Duplicate control using ShtumiUsefulBundle Symfony2

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-2.8

I'm using ShtumiUsefulBundle. This is my config section in the application:

```
shtumi_useful :
dependent_filtered_entities:
    ciudad_by_dpto:
        class: GestionBundle:Ciudad
        parent_property: dpto
        property: nombreciud
        role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
        no_result_msg: 'No hay regiones encontradas'
        order_property: nombreciud
        order_direction: ASC
```

This is my configureFormFields

```
$formMapper
        ->add('nombre')
        ->add('email')
        ->add('urlcurriculum')
        ->add('cargo')
        ->add('departamento')

        ->add('ciudad', 'shtumi_dependent_filtered_entity', array(
            'entity_alias' => 'ciudad_by_dpto',
            'empty_value' => 'Select',
            'parent_field' => 'departamento',
            'required' => true,

        ))
    ;
```

When loading the page it works perfect dependence on combos but it turns out the city combo doubled, the truth is not how or why is doubling, attached a screenshot

[image]